# use part of composite key as foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a composite key from 3 different tables. 
What i want to do is to add a reference as foreignkey from all the 3 tables. 
The problem is that 2 of the tables uses composite key. Is it possible to use just a part of the compositekey as a foreign key in another table?

[image]

So the table i want to add the foreign key to is ProductCategory and i want to add it to the property id and take that from id of the table Product.

when i do this

```
   ALTER TABLE [AAES_PAM_DEV].[dbo].[ProductCategory]
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (id)
 REFERENCES [AAES_PAM_DEV].[dbo].[Product](id)
```

i get this error:

```
    There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'AAES_PAM_DEV.dbo.Product' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__ProductCateg__id__5F492382'.
```

Comment: show the structure of your PK in the `product` table. if it was defined as `(company, id)`, then you can't use it for your FK, because `id` is "below" company.

Comment: The key for `Product` is the combination of `id` and `Company`.  So any foreign key pointing to `Product` is going to have to match that.  Otherwise the FK wouldn't be a key.

Comment: So basically i can't use entity framework to map category - productcategory- product? Because for this i need foreignkeys and i can't use foreign keys in the table where it doesn't have the whole key?